# Code-completion support for Django template language in Pycharm

Tags: django, django-templates, pycharm, code-completion

In the template files code-completion works well for `html` tags and for adding matching `{%`,

What I want is for eg: if I type `blog.` and `Ctrl + Space`, it should show me the options like `blog_title`,`blog_author` etc, that are associated with `blog`.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: I don't know what I did but somehow it is working now. So I'm deleting this question as it is not going to be helpful for others.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is possible as PyCharm has no knowledge of the type of objects you pass as context to the template. It could infer it from the view where the template is used but we are not there yet.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you register your own template tags with explicit name in your code. 
Example: register.tag ("page_attribute", PageAttribute)
See also: https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/3878 where the same thing came up.
PyCharm will recognize that and do as you asked.